# boost split - cout and vector - explain behaviour of this

Tags: c++, string, vector, boost, cout

I'm quite new to c++ and boost, I don't understand what's actually happening here.

So I'm using cin to get some input from the user. Then I'm splitting that string of spaces into a vector and trying to print the first index of the vector.

My code:

```
std::string cmd;
std::vector<std::string> args;

while (std::cin >> cmd) {
    boost::split(args, cmd, boost::is_any_of(" "), boost::token_compress_on);

    Console::print(args[0]);
    break;
    //reset the vector
    //std::cin.clear();
    //args.clear();
}
```

My console print function just uses normal cout, here is the code for it:

```
int Console::print(std::string message, int color)
{
    HANDLE consoleHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(consoleHandle, brightGreen);
    std::cout << "myconsole :: ";
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(consoleHandle, color);
    std::cout << message << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

What's happening:

For the sake of this question the input is "start go".

I only want to print the first element. Without the break my program first prints start and then it prints out go. I have determined that the program does 2 loops and each time prints the first element, I know this because if I have the break then there is only start printed and the program ends. Firstly, why is this happening? Why does the first index of the vector get removed and then looped making the first index "go"?

Does this all have something to do with the stringstream/buffer or something. I don't know much about these. That was my guess so I tried to reset the buffer with cin.clear() and empty the vector with args.clear() but that still produced the same results.

Secondly, if I use the code below and try to access the 2nd element "go" my program just crashes. From what I have tried from the above I can assume that I am correctly splitting the string.

Is there some sort of asynchronous behavior going on and the split function just isn't finished yet? Or?

Any help would be awesome. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `std::cin >> cmd` only reads "start", feeds that into the loop (which creates a single element vector and prints the only element), then loops round and does the same with "go".

You need `while(std::getline(std::cin, cmd))`.

You also need to learn to use your debugger which would have shown you what the problem was.

Comment: Thanks I am working on it :P

So the cin >> cmd line only reads up to the first space?

Comment: Reading into a string will skip whitespace (space, tab, end of line), and then read up to (but not including) the first whitespace or EOF.